# Как убрать ActionBar в ночном режиме?

Tags: android, xml

В файле с темами убрал ActionBar:

```
<style name="Theme.First_app" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
...
</style>
```

В режиме Not Night все ок работает (запускал на эмуляторе). Потом решил протестировать на своем устройстве, на котором установлен темный режим. Там появился ActionBar. Посмотрел дополнительно в дизайне через режим Night и там понятно то же самое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно убрать ActionBar при темном режиме? Нужно ли создавать отдельный стиль и связывать его с темным режимом (если и надо, то как)?

P.S.: Находил решение - скрыть ActionBar через onCreate в MainActivity, но тогда приложение вообще не запускается

Comment: А при чём здесь тёмный режим? Если у вас один вариант темы (один файл с темой) то она должна работать в любом режиме одинаково. И кроме ActionBar'а в теме у вас ещё может быть тулбар в разметке

Comment: значит у вас еще есть темная тема. в ней тоже надо изменить родительскую тему.